# Did unit confusion lead to a house with enormous doors and windows in Ypres, Belgium?

Tags: history, architecture

The [Wikipedia article on metrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metrication&oldid=742606641#Accidents_and_incidents) contains an unsourced statement regarding an incident in Ypres (Ieper), Belgium:

> During the reconstruction of Ypres after World War I, British Army engineers drew up the plans for rebuilding a bombed house in feet. However, the Belgian builders interpreted the numbers in metres. As a result, the house had enormous doors and windows.

This statement is unsourced and frankly, I find it somewhat hard to believe, as builders have brains and should imagine something is wrong *before* constructing a 6 metre high door.  I can't seem to find sources confirming this, and if true, there should be (many) contemporary press accounts including photographs.

Was a house in Ypres, Belgium rebuilt with huge proportions, due to confusing feet for metres?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I can't find anything browsing 'every' Dutch page about the reconstruction of Ieper after WW1. Let's wait for a French speaking reader doing the same ;-)

Comment: @Jan I was about to do the same when I saw your comment. So I tried French instead, with the same result. It looks as if the Belgians don't know about it.

Comment: Obligatory Spinal Tap reference - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pyh1Va_mYWI

Comment: For the record, this paragraph was added in [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metrication&type=revision&diff=534716554&oldid=534398597) of October 2013 by [User:Tavernsenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Tavernsenses). As he is still active, one might be able to contact him. (_Ieper_ was later [changed to _Ypres_](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metrication&diff=582943520&oldid=579210167))

Comment: Just as a remark to people having brains. One (two?) Mars probes malfunctioned because of exactly this type of imperial/metric confusion. I think Lockheed was a contractor and made the mistake.

Comment: @WalyKu It's different, though.  There's only a very narrow range of reasonable door heights for private homes.  There's a wide range of realistic values for pressure, elevation, etc., such that the same number can be realistic in units that differ even by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Is there a documentation of this house still existing, such as a street view address? If there is, what is the chance this is just a modernist art stunt rather than the result of a genuine, if mildly contrived, mistake?

Comment: @JanDvorak In the [revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metrication&type=revision&diff=534716554&oldid=534398597) linked by Didier L it is claimed the house still exists.  This was [removed 27 July 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metrication&diff=next&oldid=729391075), along with the citation needed mark…

Comment: As a native to Ypres, i'm not aware of such building in my town. Nor do I have ever known/heard it existed. It either doesn't exist or it isn't that spectacular.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I asked the people from the [In Flanders Fields Museum](http://www.inflandersfields.be/), which is located right in Ypres. If anyone knows about the background of the story, it should be them.

And sure enough, the nice person who responds to email inquiries at the museum shed some light on the question. Here's his response to my question about the truth of that statement:

> Yes, there is one story about the Slessorium, i.e. the bath-house that
>   was built in the early ‘30s in the garden of Talbot House. The
>   chaplain running the soldiers club sometimes used a very literary pen
>   in writing down the house history. On the building of the Slessorium,
>   he indeed reported that the flemish building company intermingled feet
>   & meters – but, as your own thoughts show, it is hard to believe that
>   this was really the case. (In the worst scenario, it can be accepted
>   that yards were taken for metres…)

He also gave me a link to a page that shows the house and what the chaplan actually wrote:

[Slessorium](http://www.wo1.be/en/db-items/slessorium)

Here's how the house looks like:

[image: Slessorium Ypres]

> The 'Slessorium', the bathhouse was named after Major Paul Slessor,
>   who acted on behalf of Lord Wakefield of Hythe when in 1929 he
>   purchased the house and on 27 October 1930 donated it to the Talbot
>   House Association. Slessor was also to prove a key figure in the
>   refurbishments of the house. He planned its funishings in every part.
>   Until his death in 1949 Slessor maintained the house with unceasing
>   care. The bathhouse built in 1931, "came out a good deal bigger than
>   in the mind's eye. The secret may be divulged that the continental use
>   of metres versus the British one of feet caused some confusion to a
>   committee studying the architect's plan in London."

I share the museum staff's judgement that the important part about metres and feet should not be taken literally. The guy was clearly just making fun. This is a rhetoric structure many people use when something didn't turn out to be the way they expected.

And most certainly, the doors and windows are not enormous.

It is a nice anecdote, for sure. But I think this one is busted.